# Will a referenced library function be linked if it is not called?

Tags: c, standards, linkage

Suppose we have the following iterface to a library:

```
// my_interface.h
typedef float (*myfunc)(float);
myfunc get_the_func();
```

And suppose that the implementation is as follows:

```
// my_impl.c
#include <math.h>
myfunc get_the_func() {
    return sinf;
}
```

And now suppose the client code does the following:

```
#include "my_interface.h"
...
myfunc func = get_the_func();
printf("%f\n", func(0.0f));
```

Does the standard guarantee that get_the_function() will return the address of the standard math library sinf()? If so, where in the standard is this implied?
Please note the sinf() is not explicitly called anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard does not require external functions to be called: being referenced is enough to be kept in the results of translation. According to the standard's section 5.1.1.2.1, during the eights (and last) phase of translation

> All external object and function references are resolved. Library components are linked to satisfy external references to functions and objects not defined in the current translation.

Since returning a pointer to a function is considered a reference to it, the standard guarantees that `sinf` will be linked to whatever implementation that you supply to the linker, which may or may not be the one coming from the standard math library.

Comment: the standard makes no such guarantee

Comment: @AhmedMasud You misunderstood the question.

Comment: Thanks for the on-the-spot answer

Answer (score 3):

The C standard doesn't guarantee that `get_the_function()` will return the address of the `sinf` function in the math library. The C standard guarantees that whatever the pointer is returned will be callable as if you called the `sinf` function and it will compare equal to any other pointer to that function.

On some architectures you might get a pointer to a descriptor of the function which the compiler handles specially and I've also seen function pointer values pointing to a dynamic linking trampoline and not the function itself.

I recall a discussion on the gcc mailing lists around 10 years ago if a function pointer cast to (void *) actually needs to compare equal to another function pointer cast to (void *) which was in connection with how IA64 implements function pointers (they could point to different descriptor structs in different libraries, which meant that to correctly implement compares the compiler would have to compare the contents of the descriptors and not the pointers themselves). But I don't remember what the standards lawyers decided and/or if this was solved in the linker.

Comment: Answers like this are .. intriguing and puzzling.  There's a claim about 'some architecture', with no mention of which architecture or discussion of what that architecture does.  You might be thinking of PowerPC and AIX; you might be thinking of something else (IBM AS/400 and relatives, perhaps). It would improve the quality of your answer to be specific. There's also an element of splitting hairs which really don't affect the OP. What is obtained from the reference to `sinf` is something that can be used as a function pointer to call the function that generates the result that `sinf` gives.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think he mentioned the architecture ia64 (which is Intel Itanium 64)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry about the late response. The magical descriptors with were on IA64. The architecture that pointed to the "dynamic linking trampoline" (PLT) was probably alpha, sparc or sparc64 and the compiler generated magical code that dug into the PLT to compare function pointers. It could have been buggy since you could get a non-NULL function pointer that could later not be resolved during lazy binding and cause a run time trap when being called or compared to another function pointer. Possibly my bugs since I was working on an ld.so at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so NOWHERE in the standard does it say that just because you  `#include <math.h>` that you will also link to the standard math library ... As a matter of fact that DOES NOT happen.

You HAVE to link to the libm in order to use the *standard* math library, as in:

```
cc -o foo foo.c -lm 
                ^^^^
```

The marked option is actually for the linker step, without it there is no linkage irrespective of whether you a function in a library as a return value or whether you use it to actually call the function.

The external symbols are resolved by either explicitly specifying the archives/objects/libraries or in case of systems / environments lazy linking during runtime through dynamic linking.

On environments that support dynamic linking, weak linking, lazy linking, etc. there is no guarantee that references will ever be resolved. For the resolution the execution path has to be traversed.

Let's say it is.  Still, your client needs to provide a linkage path for resolving *sinf* as well either when they are linking or during runtime for environments that support it.

## the point:

The client user has the ability to use any way to resolve the symbol to an address that they see fit;  So, in fact, there is no way to guarantee that your client will link to the standard library and that it will resolve to the system library sinf. The only thing you know is that if that path is executed; it will either result in an address that can be looked up using the sinf link or it will crash unceremoniously for environments that don't have to resolve the symbols at link time.

### update/clarification:

To clarify, if sinf is used as a variable; then it needs to be resolved but there is still NO guarantee that when the client code resolves the symbol when they go through their linking step that they will resolve it against the math library.  If we are talking about GUARANTEES that is.

Now practically speaking, if the client links against the standard math library and doesn't pull of any of the overrides that they can (which I pointed out above) then yes that symbol will get resolved to require a linkage against the standard library (either static or dynamic)

My original answer is a bit ehem "prissy" for which I apologize because we were talking about standards and guarantees thus the rantish nature. There is nothing for example stopping the client simply doing something like this:

foo.c:

```
#include "my_interface.h"
...
myfunc func = get_the_func();
printf("%f\n", func(0.0f));
```

first pass compile:

```
cc -o foo foo.c
```

get an error that says `sinf` is unresolved and so the client edits her source  file:

foo.c:

```
#include "my_interface.h"
...
void * sinef = NULL;
myfunc func = get_the_func();
printf("%f\n", func(0.0f));
```

and now you have a fully resolved but nicely crashing program;

Comment: You misunderstood the question: the OP not only includes `<math.h>` and links `lm`, but also returns a pointer to `sinf` without calling it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight all that requires is that sinf be resolved; where does it guarantee that it will be resolved using the standard library?

Comment: I am reasonably sure that the question was if the standard guarantees resolution in cases when there are no explicit calls of a function. The fact that's a function comes from a library, a standard library, or happens to be called `sinf` appear to be secondary to the OP.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I understand that `sinf` is not the focus :-) IMHO he wants to know whether the Does the standard >> guarantee << that get_the_function() >>will return the address of<< the standard math library. As i tried to explain that THAT only happens IF the client TOO chooses to use the standard math library to resolve the symbol(s) in question whatever they may be.

Comment: There's no such thing as 'the address of the standard math library'; there are functions in the standard math library, and they have addresses.  On some systems (Mac OS X, for example), there's no need to link a separate `-lm` maths library.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It was meant to be a quote from the OP question that I didn't put it in "". The complete phrase is: "the standard guarantee [that get_the_function()] will return the address of the standard math library [sinf()]?" I DO know that there is no such thing as a "address of the standard math library"